# C - sscanf giving me wrong output after reading file

Tags: c, file, struct, delimiter, scanf

I'm trying to read in a line from a text file in *C*, however the output is being represented wrong. I think I have done the delimiter wrong in my code. Can anyone help please?

text:

> hello, world, 1, 2, bye

output:

> hello  world 12576 117453344 bye

```
typedef struct structure {
    char hello[25];
    char world[25];
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char bye[25];
} Hello;
```

main:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structure.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[25];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    Hello c;  

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%s",
               c.hello, c.world, &c.num1, &c.num2, c.bye);
    }

    printf("%s %s %d %d %s", c.hello, c.world, &c.num1, &c.num2, c.bye);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s %s %d %d %s", c.hello, c.world, &c.num1, &c.num2, c.bye);` → `printf("%s %s %d %d %s", c.hello, c.world, c.num1, c.num2, c.bye);`

Comment: Note that your code might read 200 lines of information and then prints the result out for the last one only. You probably want the `printf()` inside the loop. You should also test the return value from `scanf()`: if it isn't 5, you've got a problem with the data. Also, while it is safe because you're using `fgets()` (thank you!), using just 24 characters per line is not generous. For long inputs, you'll process each line in multiple segments. Change `25` to `256` or something bigger. On POSIX, maybe use [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `%[^',']` for reading integers. `%d` should be used and also just to ignore `','` in string use specifier `%[^,]` in `sscanf`.

And check its return value.

Comment: Sorry for such poor formatting .Cant do much on mobile :p

Comment: Note that if you don't want the leading blanking on "`world`", you need to tell `sscanf()` to skip blanks after the comma by including a space in the format before the `%[^,]` conversion specification.  Numbers and `%s` conversions skip space automatically; only `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` don't skip white space.